# how to delete old files in a directory using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a directory for database backups, and a PHP script that makes a backup of the database every day.
But after a month or so i will have 30 files in the backup directory.
How can i write a PHP script that deletes old backup files every day so that there are always 10 backup files in my directory?
when a new backup is stored, the oldest backup file will be deleted and so on ...

Comment: Please tell me why you need PHP to do this. A simple `find` command will do it. Seems to be over egging it.

Comment: i want this to be done automatically every day ! i didn't underestand what find is ?!

Comment: Just go to http://linux.die.net/man/1/find to read about the command and figure out the parameters that is required. (exec is one that would be of interest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making the backup with the PHP backup you loop through the directory and then remove the oldest backup files:

```
$files = glob('backupfolder/*.bak');
if(count($files) > 10)
  foreach($files as $file)
    if(time() - filectime($file) > 10 * 24 * 60 * 60)
      unlink($file);
```

Comment: time() - filectime($file) returns some negative integers ! is that allright ?
numbers like :
-1348332944
-1347040386
-1347691182
-1347456987
-1347686895

Comment: Just ran a test, I do not get negative numbers (e.g. file is created in the future): index.php - 89
test.csv - 1417390
test.html - 891347
test.php - 1375369
test.xml - 1331536

Comment: i'm sorry there was a problem with my code . thanks anyway ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can read the backups directory and delete every file that is older than 30 days. However, I personally create files dynamically, and every file has this format:

`database_dump_DD-MM-YYYY_HH:MM:SS.sql`

So I can delete the files considering the filename. Since I don't know what's the format of your files, you can delete them like this:

```
$files = readdir(opendir('backups')); //read directory for files

foreach($files as $file){
    if(filemtime($file) > (time() + 2592000)){ //check if the file is older than 30 days
        unlink($file); //delete
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why go to the effort of using PHP? [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command and [cron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) would do the trick